# caffeine works but not for quodlibet

Tags: gnome-classic, quodlibet

I have caffeine installed, and it works just fine in gnome-classic (no effects) for preventing sleeping for most processes.  For example "vlc", "mplayer", and "totem" all work. I cannot get it to recognize quodlibet.  It used to work in Lucid, but after a recent upgrade, it doesn't work.

I have tried

```
qoudlibet
```

and

```
python /usr/bin/quodlibet
```

and

```
/usr/bin/quodlibet
```

as the process name, and none of them work.  Any ideas?

Comment: tag, and reference to 12.04 was removed, but it did work on 10.04 with no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QL has a proper process name since 2.4. ("quodlibet")

2.4 also includes new plugins for keeping the session active and to stop music if the session gets locked.

Use the PPA to get the last release: https://launchpad.net/~lazka/+archive/ppa

Comment: what an easy solution! not sure why I didn't think of it... thanks!